# Delete link not working in GridView

Tags: c#, sql, .net, gridview

I've set up a GridView, populated by an SQL Query, that I need to use to edit records in my SQL Database.  I can auto-create Edit and Delete links however when I select click on them, I get an error "The GridView...fired event RowDeleting which wasn't handled".  What the best way to handle the deletion or editing of a row/record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the OnRowDeleted method and OnRowDeleting method. Add those as attributes to the gridview and then implement the methods in the code behind.

See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleted(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I should clarify, I don't use the <asp:sqldatasource...> SQLDatasource, it's all done in the code (e.g. DataBind())

Comment: I know you need to add those attributes to the <asp:GridView..> The gridview is firing the OnRowDeleted method which you haven't implemented.